# What is the meaning of "We should complete it by this weekend"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, ambiguity

We assume that Saturday and Sunday are the weekend, so I am confused about the meaning of "by this weekend".

If for example in a sentence: "We should still complete the paper by this weekend."

Does it mean that it can be done till Sunday?

Comment: It's ambiguous. Ask your professor or employer to clarify whether **by** refers to the  *beginning* i.e Saturday or at the end of the weekend..

Comment: Please let us also know what your research showed you.

Comment: "We should still complete the paper by this weekend" , that is the sentence

Comment: Personally, if the working or study week is Monday to Friday I would say that the weekend stars at close of business on Friday. This would mean that the paper should be completed before the workplace or college closes on Friday. The college library might be open until 8:00pm on Friday or even 12:00 on Saturday but the weekend will start when the college closes.

Comment: @BoldBen I was thinking the same but why not just say "by Friday"? It must mean that the assignment can be finished on a Friday night and handed in on a Saturday. For example, in Italy the weekend used to commence after 13.00 on a Saturday. About 20 years ago every state school was open Saturday morning as well as many public offices.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think it's probably that both statements are ambiguous and "By Friday" could mean that the work had to be completed by midnight on Thursday, or at least by the start of the working day on Friday. It's very sloppy whichever way it's meant.